# Implementar Requisições HTTP POST e GET no Android

Tags: php, android, http, http-request

Como faço para enviar informações via get em uma url em Android, passando parâmetros? E como retornar os dados como JSON do meu PHP?

Comment: Você conseguiu resolver seu problema? Caso alguma resposta esteja correta para você, marque-a como aceita, assim outras pessoas poderão ser ajudadas.

Answer (score 4):

Utiliza-se o [Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) no android para fazer essas requisições. Volley é uma biblioteca em desenvolvimento pela própria google para controlar essas requisições.

Exemplo utilizando **JsonObjectRequest** do Volley:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

final String url = "http://www.seusite.com/get?param1=hello"; 

//Configura a requisicao
JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() 
{
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {   
        // mostra a resposta   
        Log.d("Response", response.toString());
    }
}, 
new Response.ErrorListener() 
{
     @Override
     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {            
        Log.d("Error.Response", response);
   }
});

// Adiciona a Fila de requisicoes   
queue.add(getRequest);
```

[Aqui](http://www.thiengo.com.br/volley-no-android-entendendo-e-utilizando) tem um tutorial bem explicado sobre como utilizar.

[GitHub Volley](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley) O projeto volley no GitHub.

Answer (score 3):

Java :

1º Primeiro coloque em array os seus parâmetros:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

private static final String CAMINHO_URL = "http://www.seusite.br/meuJson.php";
private static final String TAG_MENSAGEM = "mensagem";
private static final String TAG_SUCESSO = "sucesso!";

int sucesso;
MinhaClasseJsonParse jsonParser = new MinhaClasseJsonParse();
List < NameValuePair > meusGETs = new ArrayList < NameValuePair > ();
meusGETs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("meuGET", "MeuValoParaGet"));
meusGETs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("meuSegundoGET", "MeuSegundoValoParaGet"));

JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
CAMINHO_URL, "GET", meusGETs);

sucesso = json.getInt(TAG_SUCESSO);
if (sucesso == 1) {
    Log.d("Deu certo!!", json.toString());

    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGEM);
} else {
    Log.d("Estude mais!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGEM));
    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGEM);
}
```

2º Crie uma classe para executar o Json. Eu chamo ela de `MinhaClasseJsonParse:

```
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject MinhaClasseJsonParse(String url, String method, List < NameValuePair > params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        if (method == "GET") {
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer erro", "Conversão dos erros " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.i("conversor", "[" + jObj + "]");
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Erro nos dados " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

3º Execute a requisição :)

```
new SeuJsonMetodo().execute();
```

4º Crie um código PHP para receber a requisição via GET:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['meuGet']) or isset($_GET['MeuSegundoValoParaGet'])){

//Retorno em Json do meuGet

$entry = $_GET['meuGet'];
$response["oMeuGetChegou"] = $_GET['meuGet'];
echo json_encode($response);

}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Passando parâmetros via URL (GET)**

1) Utilize o formato `http[s]://servidor/pagina.php?chave1=valor1[&chave2=valor2][&chaveN=valorN]`

2) leia o conteúdo de suas chaves utilizando $_GET

```
var_dump( $_GET['chave1'] );
```

**Enviando respostas JSON via PHP**

1) Identifique o conteúdo como JSON

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

2) Serialize seu conteúdo em formato JSON, e adicione o resultado ao *response*

```
echo json_encode(conteudo);
```

Fontes:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294830/sending-encoding-response-in-json
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153218/how-to-read-the-query-string-in-php-and-html