# Android com Web Service PHP

Tags: php, android, web-service

Alguém tem um exemplo do que é preciso para recuperar os dados de um banco externo sem precisa usar o JDBC ?

Answer (score 0):

Uma opção pode ser via JSON enviando uma requisição por GET a uma variável PHP dando select em um banco externo via SQL.

Clica nesse link abaixo. Eu já respondi como faz:

[Implementar Requisições HTTP POST e GET no Android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43288/como-fazer-uma-requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-http-get-passando-dados-e-responder-com-json/43294#43294)

Answer (score 0):

Método HttpClient que é muito simples, vou colocar um exemplo. Ele tem os métodos get que não envia nenhum parametro para o Web Service e tem o Post que envia parametros, (quantos quizer...)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnManagerParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;

public class ConexaoHttpClient {

public static final int HTTP_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000;
private static HttpClient httpClient;

private static HttpClient getHttpClient(){
    if (httpClient == null){
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        final HttpParams httpParams = httpClient.getParams();

        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(httpParams, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
    }
    return httpClient;
}

public static String executaHttpPost(String url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> parametrosPost) throws Exception{
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    try{
        HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parametrosPost);
        httpPost.setEntity(formEntity);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpPost);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String LS = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            stringBuffer.append(line + LS);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();

        String resultado = stringBuffer.toString();
        return resultado;
    }finally{
        if (bufferedReader != null){
            try{
                bufferedReader.close();
            }catch(IOException erro){
                erro.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}

public static String executaHttpGet(String url) throws Exception{
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    try{
        HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        httpGet.setURI(new URI(url));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpGet);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String LS = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            stringBuffer.append(line + LS);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();

        String resultado = stringBuffer.toString();
        return resultado;
    }finally{
        if (bufferedReader != null){
            try{
                bufferedReader.close();
            }catch(IOException erro){
                    erro.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Esse é um método como exemplo, para uma tela de login:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import br.com.projetotcc.conexao.ConexaoHttpClient;
import br.com.projetotcc.utilitarios.Funcoes;
import br.com.projetotcc.visao.Activity_Atencao;
import br.com.projetotcc.visao.Activity_Principal;

public class Dao extends Activity{

String[] idPacientes;
String[] Opcao;
int posicaoPaciente;
int posicaoOpcao;

Context context;
Funcoes funcoes = new Funcoes();

public Dao(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

public void Logar(Context context, String cpf, String senha, String ip, String arquivo) throws Exception{
    String urlPost = "http://"+ip.toString()+"/projetotcc/android/"+arquivo+"";
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> parametrosPost = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    parametrosPost.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cpf", cpf));
    parametrosPost.add(new BasicNameValuePair("senha", senha));

    String respostaRetornada = null;
    Log.i("Entrou", "Vai entrar no try");

    respostaRetornada = ConexaoHttpClient.executaHttpPost(urlPost, parametrosPost);
    Log.i("Entrou", "Entrou");
    String resposta = respostaRetornada.toString();
    resposta = resposta.replaceAll("\\s+", "");

    Log.i("Logar", "Resposta: "+resposta);

    if (resposta.equals("1")){
        finish();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity_Principal.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra("senha", Integer.parseInt(senha));
        intent.putExtra("cpf", cpf);
        context.startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Usuário e ou senha inválida", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

E esse outro para retornar o ID do paciente:

```
public String[] pegarIdPaciente(Context context, String nome, String ip, String arquivo){
    String urlPost3 = "http://"+ip+"/projetotcc/android/"+arquivo+"";
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> parametrosPost3 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    parametrosPost3.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nomePac", nome));

    String respostaRetornada3 = null;

    try{
        respostaRetornada3 = ConexaoHttpClient.executaHttpPost(urlPost3, parametrosPost3);
        Log.i("Entrou", "Entrou descobrirIdPaciente");
        String resposta3 = respostaRetornada3.toString();
        resposta3 = resposta3.replaceAll("\\s+", "");

        Log.i("ID do Paciente", "ID do Paciente: "+resposta3);

        char separador3  = '#';
        int contaPacientes3 = 0;

        for (int i=0; i < resposta3.length(); i++){
            if (separador3 == resposta3.charAt(i)){
                contaPacientes3++;
                idPacientes  = new String[contaPacientes3];
            }
        }

        char caracterLido = resposta3.charAt(0);
        String nome1  = "";

        for (int i=0; caracterLido != '^'; i++){
            caracterLido = resposta3.charAt(i);
            Log.i("Chars", "Chars do paciente"+caracterLido);

            if (caracterLido != '#'){
                nome1+= (char) caracterLido;
            }else{
                Log.i("Nome", "Nome: "+nome1);
                idPacientes[posicaoPaciente] =""+ nome1;
                Log.i("Nome posição ["+posicaoPaciente+"]", ""+idPacientes[posicaoPaciente]);
                posicaoPaciente = posicaoPaciente + 1;
                nome1 = "";
            }
        }

    }catch(Exception erro){
        funcoes.mensagemSimples(context, "Erro", "Erro: "+erro);
    }
    return idPacientes;
}
```

Precisa apenas de permissão de Internet