# Aplicação apresentando este erro: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException

Tags: android, mysql, json

Estava tentando fazer um aplicação para android com conexao ao MySQL através de webservice e andou dando uns problemas, so que consegui resolver, mas apareceu esse, quando tento ver os produtos cadastrado no meu app minha LogCat aparece isso:

> 02-19 17:50:32.458: I/Choreographer(1033): Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   02-19 17:50:34.225: I/Choreographer(1033): Skipped 160 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   02-19 17:50:36.091: I/Choreographer(1033): Skipped 201 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   02-19 17:50:38.033: I/Choreographer(1033): Skipped 210 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   02-19 17:50:38.525: I/Choreographer(1033): Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   02-19 17:50:38.961: I/Choreographer(1033): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   02-19 17:50:40.260: E/JSON Parser(1033): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value ï»¿ï»¿ï»¿(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
>   02-19 17:50:52.076: E/WindowManager(1033):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:261)
>   02-19 17:50:52.076: E/WindowManager(1033):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
>   02-19 17:50:52.076: E/WindowManager(1033):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
>   02-19 17:50:52.076: E/WindowManager(1033):  at br.com.products.AllProductsActivity$LoadAllProducts.onPreExecute(AllProductsActivity.java:117)
>   02-19 17:50:52.076: E/WindowManager(1033):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
>   02-19 17:50:52.076: E/WindowManager(1033):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
>   02-19 17:50:52.076: E/WindowManager(1033):  at br.com.products.AllProductsActivity.onCreate(AllProductsActivity.java:57)
>   02-19 17:50:52.076: E/WindowManager(1033):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
>   02-19 17:50:52.076: E/WindowManager(1033):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
>   02-19 17:50:52.076: E/WindowManager(1033):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
>   02-19 17:50:52.076: E/WindowManager(1033):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
>   02-19 17:50:52.076: E/WindowManager(1033):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
>   02-19 17:50:52.076: E/WindowManager(1033):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
>   02-19 17:50:52.076: E/WindowManager(1033):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   02-19 17:50:52.076: E/WindowManager(1033):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>   02-19 17:50:52.076: E/WindowManager(1033):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>   02-19 17:50:52.076: E/WindowManager(1033):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   02-19 17:50:52.076: E/WindowManager(1033):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   02-19 17:50:52.076: E/WindowManager(1033):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>   02-19 17:50:52.076: E/WindowManager(1033):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
>   02-19 17:50:52.088: I/Choreographer(1033): Skipped 91 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   02-19 17:50:52.417: I/Choreographer(1033): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

OBS: Desculpe minha LogCat estar desajeitada, se alguem puder editar agradeço...

Minha Classe que gerencia a busca:

AllProductsActivity.java

```
package br.com.products;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "http://XXX.XXX.X.X/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_products);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                        .toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        EditProductActivity.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });

    }

    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            NewProductActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                    TAG_NAME},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

A Classe responsavel por tratar do JSON é essa:

JSONParser.java

```
package br.com.products;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Meu Arquivo PHP:

get_all_products.php

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will list all the products
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM products") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["products"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $product = array();
        $product["pid"] = $row["pid"];
        $product["name"] = $row["name"];
        $product["price"] = $row["price"];
        $product["created_at"] = $row["created_at"];
        $product["updated_at"] = $row["updated_at"];

        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["products"], $product);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que especificar mais os seus erros sobre o que se fala em `try/catch`:

```
...    
// try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
...
```

O seu erro está na obtenção do Json através da **url_all_products**. Tudo está ok no seu código java. Verifique seu `.php`. ao que parece o erro está no **echo do Json encode**. O erro pode está:

- Na obtenção do GET.

> O CORRETO ERA VOCÊ TER ESTE TIPO DE OBTENÇÃO:

[Implementar Requisições HTTP POST e GET no Android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43288/como-fazer-uma-requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-http-get-passando-dados-e-responder-com-json/43294#43294)

Comment: Tem certeza que esse é o problema, pq no erro diz que nao esta retornando um valor valido JSON...

Comment: Este é um dos erros, dos diversos. Em nenhuma parte do seu código contém erros  sobre sua pergunta, mas sim erros sobre o seu LOG. Caso você coloque o código que trate do Json, aí sim eu poderia entender melhor E EDITAR A RESPOSTA.

Comment: fiz as aletrações e nao ouve nenhuma mudança... editei a pergunta e coloquei a classe que trata do json

Comment: adicionei meu arquivo php... consegue ver onde esta o erro?

Comment: Edite a resposta.

Comment: Consegue me ajudar @Lollipop?

Comment: Mano você está enviando os dados via GET, mas no seu .php, NÃO HÁ NADA QUE O RECEBA.

Comment: Pode me ajudar a resolver, não sei mecher com php, este código peguei seguindo um tutorial

Comment: Complicado lhe ajudar se você não sabe o que ta fazendo no PHP, pois nem eu sei o que você quer  '-'

Comment: A unica coisa que eu quero é aprender a mecher com android-mysql... ai estava seguindo este tutorial => http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: o engraçado que mesmo a aplicação no android estar parando de funcionar depois de voce tentar criar o produto, no meu mysql ele cria... entao eu acho que o problema é na hora de retornar o valor, ele nao esta vindo como um valor valido JSON, saberia como converter ou algo do tipo? eu estava lendo mais e vi que preciso retirar os colchetes da resposta ("[]"), como eu faria isso? isto provavelmente é a causa..

Comment: se possivel de uma olhada neste topico => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147667/i-am-getting-error-parsing-data-org-json-jsonexception

Comment: Exatamente o quis dizer, mano. O problema está no retorno. Você está quase lá.

Comment: E.e, eu preciso descobrir uma forma de coloca os conchetes depois dos {} dessa resposta: {"products":[{"pid":"1","name":"iPhone","price":"4500.00","created_at":"2015-02-18 20:02:20","updated_at":null},{"pid":"2","name":"Motorola Moto G 2014","price":"800.00","created_at":"2015-02-19 18:56:46","updated_at":null}],"success":1}

Comment: alguem pode me ajudar?