# Consumindo um WebService em PHP

Tags: android, web-service

Configurei um WebService em PHP e preciso saber como consumir ele, sempre que faço uma busca nele ele me retorna assim:

Todos os Alertas:

get_all_alerts.php

```
{"table_alerts":[{"id":"1",
                      "category":"Visitante",
                      "name":"Rosana",
                      "city":"Sao Paulo",
                      "description":
                      "Veio tirar ferias...",
                      "created_at":"2015-02-25 16:53:23"},
                  {"id":"2",
                      "category":"Visitante",
                      "name":"Sergio",
                      "city":"Santa Cruz",
                      "description":"Mudou de Cidade",
                      "created_at":"2015-02-25 16:54:51"}],"success":1}
```

Como pego esses dados e exibo ele numa ListView no Android? Já tentei fazer isso usando usando [este tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) mas não consegui, ele não conseguia converter o valor. Alguém poderia disponibilizar um tutorial simples de como fazer isso?

Comment: Este "Todos os alertas:" faz parte do que é retornado pelo webservice? Os `>` também fazem parte do que é retornado pelo webservice? Que tutorial você usou?

Comment: @Victor, editei o topico...

Comment: @Jeiferson, isto é o suficiente: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43288/como-fazer-uma-requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-http-get-passando-dados-e-responder-com-json/43294#43294